# can i bind from event to custom component output

Tags: angular, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, angular10

i am having a custom component

```js
export class SystemInputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() ...

  @Output() enterFn: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  ...
```

that has output that act as an event *as i know*

and that component imported outside in other component html

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <system-input #systemInput></system-input>
</div>
```

the regular way to bind the event is add it into the component tag as attribute with () and bind it to a function

```html
<system-input #systemInput (enterFn)="someFunct($event)"></system-input>
```

the question is can i bind it from ts code with rxjs fromEvent function like this

**inside .ts file**

```js
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
.
.
..
@ViewChild('systemInput') systemInput:any;
ngOnInit(){
     fromEvent(this.systemInput.nativeElement,'enterFn').subscribe(a => //a is the $event );
}
..
```

and if it could how to it properly, because it give me a error

```
Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

**EDIT**
as JoH said in the first comment i moved it to ngAfterViewInit

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
     fromEvent(this.systemInput.elementRef.nativeElement,'enterFn').subscribe(a => //a is the $event );
}
```

it give me that new error

```
Invalid Event Traget
```

Comment: Move `fromEvent(this.systemInput.nativeElement,'enterFn').subscribe(a => //a is the $event );`  in `ngAfterViewInit()` method. You need to implement `AfterViewInit` interface.

Comment: i did it but it can't recognize the target, it gave me that error **Invalid event target**

Comment: where is your someFunct() method, that you are triggering? Can you show its definition?

Comment: my problem isn't with the someFunct($event) method, what i am trying to do is bind the event with **fromEvent** from rxjs to replace the regular use of it

Answer (score 1):

`nativeElement` usually used to get a reference to the HTML element class. While here you `ViewChild` of an Angular component. It doesn't have `nativeElement` property.

So to subscribe directly you don't need `fromEvent`:

```
@ViewChild('systemInput') systemInput: SystemInputComponent;
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.systemInput.enterFn.subscribe(a => //a is the $event );
}
```